# What happens when an assembler encounters a syntax error?

Tags: assembly

For example, let's say there's a code in assembly language with the following syntax:

```
LOAD 14 // loads contents of memory location 14 into the accumulator
ADD #16 // adds 16 to the contents of the accumulator
STORE 15 // stores contents of accumulator in memory index 15
```

What if "LOAD" was misspelled? What would the assembler do in this instance? Does the instruction set of the CPU affect this?

Comment: You're essentially asking _"What does a program do when it detects an error in its input?"_, and the answer is: It depends.

Comment: Too broad a question and will likely be opinionated. Realistically the result of syntax errors/typos will come down to how a lexical analyzer and the parser were designed.

Comment: Most of the assemblers will output some "syntax error" and maybe stop the compilation. Mind you, the assembling step is compiling of source into machine code, not executing it. So if your question is along the idea "will CPU panic?", then answer is not, CPU is executing final machine code and that one *can't* have syntax errors (it's not text), only the encountered byte values may form invalid instruction opcodes. Then CPU panics in some defined way (usually switching execution to some invalid-opcode handler from OS).

Comment: Do you know what an assembler does?  It just reads a text input file and assembles bytes into an output file.  It doesn't run the machine code or anything.  Why don't you just try introducing syntax errors into some asm (e.g. compiler output).

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm aware that an assembler 'compiles' assembly code into machine code, but my question is what is the assembler's response to syntax errors in assembly code? Or would it just ignore it and run, causing the CPU to 'panic' (as stated by Ped7g)

Comment: Syntax errors will generally stop assemblers from generating an executable file. Without something executable generated, you can't run it. As for causing a CPU panic, under modern OSes even a poorly created executable will not crash the system. It may crash (fault) the process but that is about it.

Comment: The assembler *doesn't run the code*, so even if a badly-designed assembler that didn't check its input did translate it to illegal instructions instead of just crashing, you'd just have a bogus binary file sitting on disk.  What Ped7g said is running illegal instructions is *not* what will happen.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, I understand that the assembly code isn't what is run, it's the machine code in binary. Sorry, I didn't really specify that.

Comment: The answer for most assemblers is that it's pretty much the same as what happens when you run a C compiler on a C program with syntax errors.  IDK why you didn't just try this yourself.

Comment: It issues an error message.

Comment: An amazingly effective way for you to answer this question for yourself is the *try it before you ask.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An assembler is just a funny kind of compiler.  It accepts a language (called the "assembly language" that it defines for the CPU it supports), and produces binary output for the assembled instructions.

Like other compilers, when it encounters a syntax error, it produces a diagnostic.   If it is good, it points out where the syntax error is precisely, but I've seen assemblers that simply  tell you which line is wrong (with maybe a hint about the error, e.g., "bad opcode").  That's not different than what lousy compilers do.

After generating the diagnostic, it often chooses some default semantic action (like generating no binary data), and continues onto the next bit of source code.

Just like a regular compiler.

The binary output of most compilers in the face of an error is usually useless; errors tend to cascade in the semantics and produce inappropriate code if it produces code at all.  (Many compilers simply stop emitting code when the first error is reported).   The binary output of an assembler in the face of an error... may still be useful.  Normally the error only affects a small part of the generated binary code.